# antd form.useWatch() error Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component

Tags: reactjs, forms, antd

I am trying to access Form.useWatch() from antd in checkAccountNumber function but I am getting this error

Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.

```
const getFieldValue = (fieldName,form) => {
    return Form.useWatch(fieldName,form);
 }

 const checkAccountNumber = () => {
    const accountNumber = getFieldValue("account_number", form)
    if(isNumeric(accountNumber))
        console.log("this true")
    else
        console.log("this is false");

 }
```

Comment: You are using Form.useWatch incorrectly. Please read react docs where you can call hooks. In your case you want to get account_number value from hook. You can use `const accountNumber = form.getFieldValue("account_number")`. You can read [Antd Form](https://ant.design/components/form#forminstance) api for other form methods.

Answer (score 0):

[Hooks Can't be call inside function](https://legacy.reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html#:%7E:text=Hooks%20can%20only%20be%20called,breaking%20the%20Rules%20of%20Hooks.). Only in Component.

```
const Component = () => {
 const accountNumber = Form.useWatch("account_number", form)
}
```

If you want to use that write a custom hook.

```
const useCheckNumber = () => {

    const accountNumber = Form.useWatch("account_number", form);

    if(isNumeric(accountNumber))
        return true
    else
       return false
 }

}
```

Comment: I am getting the same error